# how to injection a global filter property with autofac mvc3?

Tags: autofac

`builder.RegisterFilterProvider();`

This can inject a property in filter write on an action like:

```
[TestFilter]
public ActionResult SomeAction(){...}
```

But can not inject a global filter register at global.asax like

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{

    filters.Add(new TestFilterAttribute());

}
```

Can I do something else?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO. It's not really clear what you're asking here. If you can give us more detail about what you're trying to do perhaps we'll be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the property when register the global filter on global.asax

```
filters.Add(new TestFilterAttribute() { TObj=AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.ApplicationContainer.Resolve<ITest>() });
```

i try some way

```
builder.RegisterType<TestFilterAttribute>().PropertiesAutowired()

builder.RegisterType<TestFilterAttribute>().OnActivating(x=>x.Instance.TObj=x.Context.Resolve<ITest>())

builder.RegisterType<TestFilterAttribute>().WithProperty("TObj",new Test())
```

all above not work

or

```
builder.RegisterType<TestFilterAttribute>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

and filter register with code like:

```
filters.Add(AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.ApplicationContainer.Resolve<TestFilterAttribute>());
```